# PHPUnit configuration (phpunit.xml) -- loading in a bootstrap?

Tags: php, configuration, phpunit, bootstrapping

## Situation

We're using PHPUnit in our project and are using a `phpunit.xml` to ensure things like `backupGlobals` is turned off.

To further ensure the include path is set and autoloading is active, we also cascade our test bootstraps. That is to say, every test and alltests-suite has a `require_once(__DIR__ . '/../bootstrap.php');` at the top, all the way up to the base folder level, where it obviously reads `require_once(__DIR__ . '/bootstrap.php');`, and the actual bootstrap file resides.

Essentially, our tests are autonomous. You can call any `AllTests.php` in any folder and any `*Test.php` by itself and they'll run with the right configuration.

Except no. '*Wait a moment.*'

That's only true if we either force our developers to use `phpunit --configuration=path/to/phpunit.xml` or they're in the folder with the `phpunit.xml` (so that PHPUnit pulls it out of the current working directory when it is executed).

Occasionally, this makes it incredibly hard to determine why tests on one developer's machine are breaking and why they're running on another. It just takes forgetting that the bootstrap is *not* the only thing we need to have the same test environment. Keep in mind that since you couldn't forget the bootstrap if you tried, because it's in the tests themselves, forgetting other settings, especially usually-optional ones like that (if you're in the folder with the `phpunit.xml`, it's automatically pulled), is easy.

In fact - it's happened a few times.

## Question

**Is there a way I can supply which `phpunit.xml` to use in the test file being run,** such as in our conveniently ubiquitous bootstrap file, **rather than supplying it to PHPUnit beforehand**, be that by command-line switch or by being in its directory **?**

A cursory glance at the code suggests the answer is no - configuration well and truly seems to be loaded before test files are even pulled:

```
[PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php]
...
if (isset($this->arguments['configuration'])) {
    $configuration = PHPUnit_Util_Configuration::getInstance(
        $this->arguments['configuration']
    );
    $phpunit = $configuration->getPHPUnitConfiguration();
    ...
```

That does make some sense, given that the configuration can contain test white- or blacklists.

Really, it wouldn't make sense to load test *filters* in the test bootstrap itself, so that's half the potential configuration out the window with, but the actual behavioural flags of PHPUnit...

```
[sample of part of our phpunit.xml]
<phpunit
    backupGlobals="false" 
    backupStaticAttributes="false" 
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"  
    convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
    syntaxCheck="false"
    processIsolation="false"
    colors="true">
```

...perhaps with the exception of 'colors' strikes me as something that the test itself should be able to decide on some level.

## Consolation prize for...

Admittedly, right now I'd be happy just knowing if I can teach PHPUnit `backupGlobals="false"` from the bootstrap file, if someone knows of a way.

*(If fruitless, the practical answer I'll pursue will probably be to copy the `phpunit.xml` into all subfolders. I'd like to avoid that solution since it creates redundant copies, and if we ever choose to change a setting... yeah, ouch!)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Direct answer: No, you can't do that.

Longer story - this kind of problem is better solved by changing the habits of developers.

Here is we do it:

- All developers always run the tests from the tests root directory, which has the sole `phpunit.xml` with all the necessary configuration - including bootstrap, which sets up an class autoloader.
- We don't have testsuites as such, tests are grouped using directories, no AllTests.php anywhere, because its not necessary. PHPUnit can take a name of directory and run all tests inside it.
- Its still possible to run any single test by giving a path to it or whole testsuite (by giving path to the directory). It just has to be done from the tests root directory all the time or it won't work.

Doing it like this means giving up the freedom of starting PHPUnit from any directory, but to be honest - I don't feel like that's a loss at all.

The gains are much bigger: the amount of housekeeping code is reduced, developers cannot forget anything and results are therefore consistent.

Comment: See, our problem is that we do have that first policy - but the devs are told it once and there's nothing reminding them to do it. It works 99 out of a hundred cases, when you want to run the whole test suite anyway, because you have to make sure your changes weren't build-breaking, and you do that from the root directory - and then is forgotten when you want to do a quick retest of a directory branch.

Comment: In that, I reckon your point #2 is very insightful; perhaps removing AllTests.php in the subdirectories would 'force' the thought process a little better, serve as a reminder of the `phpunit.xml`. I'll give that some more thought and bounce it off my colleagues, maybe that's the better solution.

Comment: It is a choice between changing the habits and creating a maintenance hell (with lots of config files that need to be synced). Good luck :)

Answer (score 5):

My solution is to add a bash function

```
function phpu ()
{
  phpunit --colors --bootstrap ~/path/to/bootstrap.php "$@";
}
```

Then add this to all dev .bashrc files and they can switch to using that.

We like to call them from `vim` so I had to add this to `.vimrc`: `set shellcmdflag=-ic`

Then you add `nmap ;t :! phpu %` to run the test file you're currently in.

Answer (score 0):

You could update the start script (Windows bat file, or shell on *nix) and have logic in there to configure to the location of the phpunit.xml.  If it is in the current directory, use it, otherwise point to the main one.

I also agree with Anti though, that all the tests should always be run, as you want to ensure that the changes, even in a directory branch, do not affect other code. Therefore, always run from the top of the tree.  This also requires that the test execute quickly, but I have not really had a problem with PHPUnit on that.

Maintaining the PHPUnit.xml in each directory would be a maintenance nightmare, unless is was symbolically linked from other paths to ensure there was only one actual file.